# How would someone create an ID for SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have had a good look around and I, so far, haven't been able to find an answer to my question.

Bit of background;
I am new to SQL but very interested in learning. Due to moving country soon, instead of finding a job at an entry level, I am studying towards my certifications, but there are some things that books do not cover.

Now, when creating tables I understand the concept of creating a unique identifier, and I understand that there are many ways to do it, either by using;

** 'uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid()'

or

'int primary key identity' **

when creating the table.

I understand the use for each one, but my question is,

**How would someone create an ID for SQL that is sequential but doesn't start at 1?**

is it possible to start with 8 digits(00000001), like an employee ID for example, or are there limitations in place preventing SQL from starting anywhere other than (1)

Thanks for reading Ladies and Gents.

You guys don't mess around! thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that your 8-digit example is still starting at 1, just formatted differently... typically formatting like that would be handled at the application layer.

Comment: You can set AutoIncrement something like this for sure instead of 1 -- AUTO_INCREMENT=10000

Comment: It's recommended to have Primary Keys as **integers**.

Comment: would 'TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=10000' not create an increment by 10000 everytime?

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of using your primary key on your table as a public identifier! I say this in response to your example of using the PK as a employee ID.  It works great up until the customer decides they want to make a "small" change to its format or you need to merge databases. It takes no work to create a second column in the same table to store identifying information, just throw an Unique index on it and you are good!

Comment: Deadron is right.  Use autoincrement integers (not uniqueidentifier guids) for your PK, and keep them internal to the application.  Never show the autoincrement ID to the user, or they will construct all sorts of trouble about it.  Give them a second number field to do with as they like, and keep the PK strictly for internal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-SQL you can set an identity seed using the following syntax

```
YourID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1000, 1)
```

This will start at 1000 and go up by one with each increment.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx

If you want to pad the number with zeros, I don't think you can do this with an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom sequences using the [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff878091.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 0):

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;

Answer (score 0):

using dbcc checkident, you can set your identity column to any integer value any time.